# What is a WhereSelectArrayIterator in Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have an array of strings.  I'm trying to write them to an element.  When I create a new element it works as it's supposed to, when i try to SetElementValue it doesnt. Any help would be appreciated.  I don't even know what to look up.

Working Properly:

```
new XElement("tags", blog.tags.Select(x =>
    new XElement("tag", PageUtilities.AddCDATAElements(PageUtilities.SanitizeXmlString(x)))))
```

Result in Xml File:

```
<tags>
  <tag>&lt;![CDATA[tag1]]&gt;</tag>
  <tag>&lt;![CDATA[tag2]]&gt;</tag>
  <tag>&lt;![CDATA[tag3]]&gt;</tag>
  <tag>&lt;![CDATA[tag4]]&gt;</tag>
</tags>
```

The problem comes in when i try to update:

Not Working:

```
xBlog.SetElementValue("tags", blog.tags.Select(x =>
    new XElement("tag", PageUtilities.AddCDATAElements(PageUtilities.SanitizeXmlString(x)))));
```

Result:

```
<tags>System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]</tags>
```

At a total loss.  Please help.  Thanks you guys!

For Simplicity I tried it without the AddCDATAElements and SanitizeXMLString and still the exact same result

xBlog.SetElementValue("tags", blog.tags.Select(x => new XElement("tag", x)));

System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]

Comment: That's the result of ToString being called on a query object.  What does AddCDATAElements return?

Comment: &lt;![CDATA[tag1]]&gt; - Just the string with cdata wrapped around the result.  I just dont understand why it works perfectly with the new Element, but the setElementValue it doesnt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you're passing an `IEnumerable` into the constructor, and the code is smart enough to figure out what you're doing and loop on it. I took a peek at the constructor (with ReSharper), and it seems that if what you're passing is an IEnumerable, it loops and creates an `XNode` for each item in the list.

In the second case, you're passing an IEnumerable to `SetElementValue`. But it doesn't check to see if the parameter is an IEnumerable. It does some basic type checking to see if it's a string, int, etc, and finally it just calls `ToString`, which in your case returns the name of the type of variable that is being produced by `blog.tags.Select(x => ...)`.

Storing the result in a list first, and looping should solve the issue, but then I'm not sure what you want to do with each item in the list.

```
var elements = blog.tags.Select(x =>
    new XElement("tag", PageUtilities.AddCDATAElements(PageUtilities.SanitizeXmlString(x))))

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    // do something with each element
}
```

Comment: I want to replicate the same result as in the working one.  The working one is in AddBlog(), the not working one is in UpdateBlog().  I pass in an array of tags and want to store them,  like in the new Xelement, the SetElementValue is just taking the existing xml and updating the tags section with the new list of tags.

Comment: Your solution worked for me.  I did  foreach (string t in blog.tags)
                    {
                        xBlog.Element("tags").Add(new XElement("tag", t));  It just seems a little clunkier than the first way.  But works perfectly. Thanks!!  
                    }

Comment: Grant.  I appreciate the wisdom, have a nagging question, for the sake of knowing.  Is there a way to make SetElementValue see the Ienumerable, instead of just calling to string?

Answer (score 0):

Select will always return an Enumerable of items.  Looks like SetElementValue will just do a ToString() on the value of that parameter.  If you want a single element's value, use .First().Value after the .Select().  If you want all of them, you'll probably need to add more code to generate multiple elements and add them to the value.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what your data is, but did you try to put a `ToList()` or `ToArray()` after the linq? that will make the enumerable into either.